# Añadir SCSS a GIT

Tags: git, github, scss, gitlab, control-de-versiones

Estoy tratando de añadir ficheros `.scss` a mi controlador de versiones, uso GIT sobre un entorno GITLAB.

El problema viene cuando intento importar la carpeta CSS. Me importa sin ningún problema los ficheros `.css`, pero los `.scss` parece que los omite.

La carpeta CSS cuenta con la siguiente estructura:

```
css/
   _variables.scss
   style.css
   style.scss
   fichero.css
   fichero.scss
```

Y el fichero .gitignore tiene la siguiente estructura

```
!css/*.scss
```

¿Existe algún problema a la hora de importar ficheros `.scss` a git?

***EDIT 1 Fichero .gitignore***

```
\.vscode/
/node_modules
/dist
/src/css/*.css
/src/php/conexion.php
!/src/css/fonts.css
/Versiones/*/dist
/Versiones/*/node_modules
/Versiones/*/src/components
/Versiones/*/src/custom-components
/Versiones/*/src/index.html
/Versiones/*/src/css/*.css
/Versiones/*/src/js/*/*.*
/Versiones/*/src/js/*.*
!/Versiones/*/src/js/config/*.*
!/Versiones/*/src/css/*.scss
```

Comment: Con este comando puedes mirar qué regla está haciendo que el fichero se ignora: `git check-ignore -v css/fichero.scss`

Comment: Recibo una linea en blanco al hacer el comando, entiendo que no hay nada que lo bloquee. De echo, en otras carpetas del mismos proyecto si que importa los .scss sin problemas, es algo muy raro.

Comment: La estructura `!css/*.scss` está diciendo: deja de ignorar los ficheros `.scss` en `css/`. Por tanto, entiendo que más arriba estás ignorándolos de alguna forma; en caso contrario, esta línea no tiene sentido.

Comment: Añado el fichero real, no veo ninguna configuración que choque entre ellas. ¿No?

Comment: ¿cómo añades los ficheros a git?

Comment: Uso GitKraken, según va detectando cambios, stagin area, commit... Es el proceso normal ¿no?

Comment: ¿Has hecho `git add .gitignore`? ¿Es decir, has actualizado el gitignore para que esté aplicando el contenido actual?

Comment: Si, .gitignore está actualizado y de hecho, si obligo a importar el fichero en concreto !/Versiones/*/src/css/index.scss no hace nada, cambio el .scss por .css y me coge las 24 coincidencias que tiene.